# how can I send my image with chunks with fetch/https?

Tags: node.js, express, remix.run

I want to upload a image to bunny and here is a example from them

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const REGION = 'YOUR_REGION'; // If German region, set this to an empty string: ''
const BASE_HOSTNAME = 'storage.bunnycdn.com';
const HOSTNAME = REGION ? `${REGION}.${BASE_HOSTNAME}` : BASE_HOSTNAME;
const STORAGE_ZONE_NAME = 'YOUR_STORAGE_ZONE_NAME';
const FILENAME_TO_UPLOAD = 'filenameyouwishtouse.txt';
const FILE_PATH = '/path/to/your/file/upload.txt';
const ACCESS_KEY = 'YOUR_BUNNY_STORAGE_API_KEY';

const uploadFile = async () => {
  const readStream = fs.createReadStream(FILE_PATH);

  const options = {
    method: 'PUT',
    host: HOSTNAME,
    path: `/${STORAGE_ZONE_NAME}/${FILENAME_TO_UPLOAD}`,
    headers: {
      AccessKey: ACCESS_KEY,
      'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    },
  };

  const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log(chunk.toString('utf8'));
    });
  });

  req.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });

  readStream.pipe(req);
};

const main = async () => {
  await uploadFile();
};

main();
```

now my question is when I send my uploaded file to my post route how can I now to make a createReadStream ?

example how I recieve my image (Blob file)
BTW: I use remix with express

```
export const action: ActionFunction = async ({ request, params }) => {
  try {
    const d = await request.formData();
    const blob = d.get('image');
    
   // now what to do ?

    return null;
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    return e;
  }
};
```